# Dual Sheaf of Coherent Sheaf Quasi Coherent

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be curve $f:C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ a finite morphism. This implies that $C= Spec(\mathcal{A})$ where $\mathcal{A}= f_*(\mathcal{O}_C)$ is the induced **coherent** relative $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$-algebra.

Let consider it's dual, the $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$-module $\underline{Hom}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$. By the locally canonical $\mathcal{A}$-action via $s \times h \mapsto (a \mapsto h(sa))$ the $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$-module $\underline{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}(\mathcal{A})$ becomes an $\mathcal{A}$-module.

My question is why $\underline{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$ is **quasi coherent**?

My ideas: The problem is local. So choosing an affine open set $U = Spec(R) \subset \mathbb{P}^1$ we get $\mathcal{A}|_{f^{-1}(U)} = Spec(A)$ for finite presented $R$-module $A= \Gamma(U, \mathcal{A})$, so $A$ is the cokernel of the map $$R^m \to R^n$$.

Quasi coherence is a local property so is whould suffiece to show that $Hom_R(A,R)$ is a cokernel of a map $$A^I \to A^J$$ where $I,J$ are arbitrary index sets, or equivalently the sequence 
$$0 \to A^I \to A^J \to Hom_R(A,R) \to 0$$
is exact...
but from here I don't know what to do (so how to use the finite presentation of $A$)

Comment: Maybe Exercise 13.7.A in Ravi Vakil's Math 216 notes will help.

Comment: @danneks: Hi, thank you for the enlightening hint. One thing stays unclear to me: If I follow the hint given in exercise 13.7A where it suffice to show that $Hom_R(A,R)$ commutates with localisations by prime ideals $(p) \subset R$ I only get that $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)= \widetilde{Hom_R(A,R)}$ holds, so by 1-to-1- correspondence between $R$-modules and quasi-coherent sheafs  I get that $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)$ is quasi coherent as $R$-module, **not** as $A$ module

Comment: In other words $Hom_R(A,R)$ "sits" in sequence $0 \to R^I \to R^J \to Hom_R(A,R) \to 0$, not in $ 0 \to A^ {I'} \to A^ {J'} \to Hom_R(A,R) \to 0 $. By the way: $A$ not flat, so tensoring $ - \otimes A$ would brake the first exact sequence...